# Button with multiple text and image

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design an xml & in that i want 2 textview and 1 image on the button.i tried framelayout and relative layout but it is not working. plz help me.one textview should be on the topleft side of the button,image on the top right side and another textview in the center
first textview is distance,another is speed and i am storing the distance and speed in the database. and i want to display the values of distance and speed on the button

Answer (score 2):

I think the easy way to do this is by making a picture with all the text and image and then putting it as the image in an `imageButton`

**EDIT**

Use `RelativeLayout` and make it `android:clickable="true"` it will act as a button then.

Comment: the two textviews that i am using on the button, one for distance and other for speed .. i want to show that value as text on the button. so i cant use the image with text.

Comment: In your question u should have provided this information

Comment: sorry for that.. Now i provided the full question.can u help me now

Comment: It depends on TextViews and Button locations. Maybe LinearLayout will be better